# Find() method of list

Tags: c#, list, object

I have a login method.
My data is organized like this:

```
public class globalLists
{
    public List<course> courseList = new List<course>();
    public List<user> userList = new List<user>();
    public List<string> registeredUsernameList = new List<string>();
```

I have a class with 3 lists that is static-instantiated

```
public class user
{
    public int currentCourse = 0;
    public course[] courseQ = new course[10];
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
```

Next is the `logOn` class, with the BLL `Logon` User method

```
public static class logOn
{
    static BusinessEntities.user userAccess = new BusinessEntities.user();

    public static bool BLLLogonUser(string username, string psw)
    {

        userAccess.username = username;
        userAccess.password = psw;

        int index = userlist.FindIndex(a => a.username == userAccess.password);
        BusinessEntities.user pswss = user.Find(a => (a.password == userAccess.password) && (a.username == userAccess.username));

        if (pswss.) // ignore this
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I have 2 objects, the instantiated one called User Access, his attributes are username and password from `BLLLogonUser()` parameters.

AND the object `pssws` which actually was named hitting the keyboard,

My question is: `pssws` will search for a object on the list that meet the conditions given and take all the other values from found object?

```
BusinessEntities.user pswss = user.Find(a => (a.password == userAccess.password) && (a.username == userAccess.username));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is: pssws will search for a object on the list that meet the conditions given and take all the other values from found object?

No, especially since you are calling `Find` on the `user` object, when this is a property of `List` type. This will be a compilation error.

> Modified Code (use the `userList`)

```
BusinessEntities.user pswss = userList.Find(a => (a.password == userAccess.password) && (a.username == userAccess.username));
```

This will fill the correct reference object from the `List` and since it is a reference so it will point to the object in the `List`, thus contain all the properties. Thus, any modification to the Object will change the object in the `List` (this is shallow copy not deep copy)

> Better Option

Use `System.Linq, Where` and modify as follows:

```
BusinessEntities.user pswss = userList.FirstOrDefault(a => (a.password == userAccess.password) && (a.username == userAccess.username));
```

**Edit 1: (Answer the OP question)**

`Where` / `FirstOrDefault` was introduced in Linq, and applied on the all the collections derived from `IEnumerable<T>`, which means literally all the collection, thus wider in usage. `Find` is only `List<T>` method, which was introduced in .Net 2.0, thus precedes Linq.
In terms of performance, both of them will be O(N) linear search, so not much difference though `Linq` is convenient / self descriptive in usage. If the number of records are high and performance is impacted due to size of the collection, then consider converting `List` to `Hashset` for `O(LogN)` search or `Dictionary`, if the data is compatible (as it needs Unique Key) for quickest O(1) search

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for answer, i modified that, but, whats the difference between using find() and where clause?

Comment: Check out the edited answer, to use `FirstOrDefault`, in place of `Where` as you just need 1 object. It also answers the other questions that you have, with additional Data structure information.

Comment: Of curse you do, you save my a*s :D, ty, it worked with both find() and where(), you deserve it sr